# How does one align all lines into the same position in VIM?

Tags: vim

So in VIM,  I do select all the lines demanded using `V` (visual-line mode).

Then I want to align all the lines into she same position, how do you do that?

If you look at a the screen, you will notice that I have selected the lines and then I can possibly do `<` but that will only align some of the lines to the very beginning and then I have to press `>` in order to align them outwards.

Can I align all the lines into the same position?

[image: How to align into the same position?]

Comment: You should add the desired result in order to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

From [:left](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aleft):

```
                                                        :le :left
:[range]le[ft] [indent]
                        Left-align lines in [range].  Sets the indent in the
                        lines to [indent] (default 0).
```

Comment: Hey danadam, that is great, much helpful, thank you. One last question, do you know where I can possibly change indent to, say, 1 or 2 spaces instead of default 0? Is it in .vimrc?

Comment: As far as I know that is not configurable. If you often use a specific value you can create mapping for it, e.g.: `noremap <leader>i :left 2<CR>`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
 gg=G
```

Because the `=` in normal mode reindents lines based on your settings

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply guys. Left works fine after updating .vimrc. I do not know what you mean by gg=G? Am I supposed update .vimrc with this? How you use it in experience with VIM? When I use CTRL + V alas VISUAL BLOCK, mark couple lines and then press G or gg, It will mark all the lines on the page as it scrolls the page down..

Comment: If you have any selection just type `=` to reindent  [@grooveinshell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18107424/grooveinshell)

Comment: Nice, thank you. I just did not understang those gg letters. But htanks for the advice.